# Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY vs Projections.distinct

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, distinct, hibernate-criteria

I am pretty new to Hibernate. I found out that we can get distinct result using following two different ways. Could any one tell me what is the difference between them? When to use one over other?

```
Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id"));
```

vs

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

While similar names, the usage is different.

#### I. `Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id"));`

this statement would be translated into SQL Statement. It will be passed to DB Engine and executed as a SQL `DISTINCT`. See:

- [17.9. Projections, aggregation and grouping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-projection)

so e.g. this example:

```java
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Projections.distinct(Projections.property("id")) )
    )
    .list();
```

would seems like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(cat_id) FROM cat_table
```

#### II. `criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);`

This statement is executed **ex-post**. Once the SQL query from DB engine is returned and Hibernate iterates the result set to convert that into list of our entities.

But is it needed always? NO, mostly this is not needed.

> The only case, when we MUST to use that, if there is an association in the query - JOINING the `one-to-many` end.

Because if we do have one **`cat`** and its two **`kittens`**, this would return **two** rows, while `cat` is **only** one:

```sql
SELECT cat.*, kitten.*
FROM cat_table as cat 
  INNER JOIN kitten_table kitten ON kitten.cat_id = cat.cat_id
```

So, the statement at the end of the `criteriaQuery`:

```java
... // criteriaQuery joining root and some one-to-many
.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
```

would result in a list with only one cat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. It is very well explained. I almost finished reading Beginning Hibernate book, but I still couldn't figure out about Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY. Your answer with an example made me clear.

Comment: i have a doubt, how can u make in the first example it returns, the class, and not only the id, do u know what i mean? thanks.

Comment: We can use the distinct id and use it using HQL to get distinct rows from a class, I don't think it is good idea in terms of the performance though.

Comment: But will the only one cat have both kitten?

Comment: I know this is very old, but can you explain what DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY does in actual SQL terms? The way you described it in your answer is "You have one row A which is 1-n and results in two rows B, you apply DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY and it *magically* results in one row B" - how? I'm honestly quite stumped on how to replicate this in a query I'm building (has nothing to do with java)

Answer (score 3):

From docs:
DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
Each row of results is a distinct instance of the root entity

distinct() selects distinct by property, in you case by identifier

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understood second line but because of lack of knowledge about root entity, I didn't understand first line completely. It was still very helpful.