# Hibernate problems with Spring GrantedAuthorities and related objects

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I've started using Hibernate together with SpringSecurity and GrantedAuthorities.

When querying the database I'm getting wrong results now.

**User:**

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_authorities",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority")
    )
    private List<Authority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Authority:**

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Authority implements GrantedAuthority {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String authority;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Order:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private User owner;
}
```

The problem is that Hibernate now lists all `Orders` multiple times, depending on how many `Authorities` a `User` has.

If a `User` has 3 `Authorities` and 2`Orders`, the following 6 objects appear in my DAO:

```java
+----------+---------+------------+
| Order id | User id | Authority  |
+----------+---------+------------+
|        1 |       1 | ROLE_USER  |
|        1 |       1 | ROLE_ADMIN |
|        1 |       1 | ROLE_TEST  |
|        2 |       1 | ROLE_USER  |
|        2 |       1 | ROLE_ADMIN |
|        2 |       1 | ROLE_TEST  |
+----------+---------+------------+
```

This is the related Hibernate query:

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Order> getOrdersForUser(User user) {

    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Order.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("owner", user))
            .list();

}
```

Can someone provide insight on this behaviour? I don't think that's how Hibernate should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try with:

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(Order.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("owner", user))
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
        .list();
```

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536868/criteria-distinct-root-entity-vs-projections-distinct)