# how to write Hibernate Criteria to take nested list objects by Projection List?

Tags: java, hibernate

my question is similar to this question [how to write Hibernate Criteria to take nested objects by Projection List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970214/how-to-write-hibernate-criteria-to-take-nested-objects-by-projection-list)

but with tiny differnce. In fact my classes is  similar to

```
  class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Car> cars; // differnce 
    // getters and setters
  }
```

how transformer to list of objects?

Comment: Why do you have a list of `String`? Shouldn't that be a list of `Car`? That's no object relation ;)

Comment: @Jan yes that is right:)

Comment: Ok :) just to clarify your question a bit more: You want to receive a list of cars? Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852230/adding-a-projection-to-a-list-in-hibernate) help?